# Curl not working in one server, but OK in all others

Tags: php, xml, curl

below code is not working on one server, but working fine in others. I am getting this error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: HR line 1 and body in testchecker.php on line 11
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): dden.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/5.5.20</h3></body> in testchecker.php on line 11
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in testchecker.php on line 11
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: HR line 1 and html in testchecker.php on line 11
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Premature end of data in tag body line 1 in testchecker.php on line 11
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Premature end of data in tag html line 1 in testchecker.php on line 11
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in testchecker.php on line 12


    <?php
set_time_limit(0);

$url="http://test";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
foreach($xml->User as $child){
    echo $child->Id."<br/>";        
}
?>
```

I dont understand why this error is getting, because in local and other servers its working fine. On dreamhost, its not. Can anybody help me in this.

Comment: 1) do not use printscreens if you can paste text info into the question and 2) indicate in your code which lines the errors complain about.

Comment: updated, please see

Comment: 1 - verify php5-curl package is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.
The ip was blocked, so forbidden message was getting, instead of xml.
Unblocking the ip fixed everything.

Comment: So you may now delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

The error message already tells you, what is wrong

> ```
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: HR line 1 and body in testchecker.php on line 11  
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): dden.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/5.5.20</h3></body> in testchecker.php on line 11
> ```

XML requires all tags be closed, while with HTML, you can omit the closing tag occasionally.

In this case, you have a `<hr>` tag without a corresponding closing tag. This is perfectly valid in HTML. However, it is not well-formed XML, which is required by [`simplexml_load_string`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string)

> **Description**
>   Takes a well-formed XML string and returns it as an object.

Comment: but there all tags are closed. but dont know why still i am getting same eror